# Rolling join with group ID in both tables

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

We have two dataframes, a first with dates of aired ads for a set of products and a second of dates of sales for the same set of products.
We'd like to attach for each ad of each product, the closest sale, AFTER the ad.

Here's the code for the inputs :

```
original_table = data.table(article = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B'), 
                            date_ad = as.Date(c('2010-04-09','2011-07-12','2012-05-22','2011-07-12','2014-02-02','2015-04-13','2016-08-12'),))

> original_table
   article    date_ad
1:       A 2010-04-09
2:       A 2011-07-12
3:       A 2012-05-22
4:       B 2011-07-12
5:       B 2014-02-02
6:       B 2015-04-13
7:       B 2016-08-12

table_to_join = data.table(article = c('A','A','B','B','B'), 
                           date_sale = as.Date(c('2010-12-15','2012-08-20','2013-12-01','2016-01-05','2017-01-20'),))

> table_to_join
   article  date_sale
1:       A 2010-12-15
2:       A 2012-08-20
3:       B 2013-12-01
4:       B 2016-01-05
5:       B 2017-01-20
```

After attaching the dates from the second table to the ones in the first one, the output should have the following format :

```
> result
   article    date_ad  date_sale
1:       A 2010-04-09 2010-12-15
2:       A 2011-07-12 2012-08-20
3:       A 2012-05-22 2012-08-20
4:       B 2011-07-12 2013-12-01
5:       B 2014-02-02 2016-01-05
6:       B 2015-04-13 2016-01-05
7:       B 2016-08-12 2017-01-20
```

P.S : `original_table` can potentially have many more rows than `table_to_join`, for each article. Multiple rows in `original_table` could be linked to the same row from `table_to_join`.

How can we get that in an efficient way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a rolling join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
table_to_join[, date_ad := date_sale][original_table, 
       on = .(article, date_sale = date_ad), roll = -Inf]
#   article  date_sale    date_ad
#1:       A 2010-04-09 2010-12-15
#2:       A 2011-07-12 2012-08-20
#3:       B 2015-04-13 2016-01-05
#4:       B 2016-08-12 2017-01-20
```

---

I think OP was confused with the naming of the output columns. Using an update by reference should be clearer:

```
table_to_join[, date_ad := date_sale]
original_table[, date_sale :=
    table_to_join[.SD, on=.(article, date_ad), roll=-Inf, x.date_sale]
]
```

output:

```
   article  date_sale    date_ad
1:       A 2010-04-09 2010-12-15
2:       A 2011-07-12 2012-08-20
3:       A 2012-05-22 2012-08-20
4:       B 2011-07-12 2013-12-01
5:       B 2014-02-02 2016-01-05
6:       B 2015-04-13 2016-01-05
7:       B 2016-08-12 2017-01-20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, here's what I'm getting : 
Error in `[.data.table`(table_to_join, , `:=`(date_sale, date_ad)) : 
  Supplied 36138255 items to be assigned to 169538 items of column 'date_sale'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: @mix This was based on your example, sorry,

Comment: Okay, I added a note at the end of my post to make it clear that the first table could potentially have more samples many of which could be linked to the same sale date.

Comment: @mix it is not the sample size, it would be the duplicate values for the joining column

Comment: @mlx if you make it unique, may be it works, i.e. `table_to_join[, date_ad := date_sale][unique(original_table, by = 'date_ad), on = .(article, date_sale = date_ad), roll = -Inf]`

Comment: two different articles could have the same date_ad. Applying unique and only passing "date_ad" to the by argument would raise issues for the final result.

Comment: @mlx sorry, i can't reproduce this with an example you showedd that is working fine with the solutoin

Comment: Update on this : @akrun your solution does indeed work.       
I'm only encountering one issue, the produced table of your code is swapping the columns' names. Could you check that ?

Comment: @mix IIt would be because it is named `date_ad := date_sale`, could you name it to a different name and then try on it though I couldn't reproduce the issue you showed

Comment: If you check my output (initial message) and your output (modification brought by @chinsoon12), values of columns are the same but the columns' names are swapped. d

Comment: @mlx if it is the column names issues, if `out` is the output object` use `setnames` to change the names i.e. `setnames(out, 2:3, c('date_ad', 'date_sale'))`